# Communication between Activities with setResult() from one activity and onActivityResult() from the other

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity

I am a total newbie with Java and Android programming.

What I have is an Activity which upon clicking a button it launches a different activity with a selectbox (a friendpicker for facebook).

What I want to do is, upon selecting the users I want, display them in the first activity. 
As a second goal I would try to create a button for every user. But first I only to get the information from one activity to another.

I figured setResult() and onActivityResult() would be my right choice. I am not sure how and why to do it.

so in my second activity, this contains all the users I want:

```
List<GraphUser> friendList = friendPickerFragment.getSelection();
```

but this obviously does not work:

```
setResult(RESULT_OK, (Intent) friendListToPlay);
finish();
```

How am I getting my List of GraphUser Objects into this intent?

then on my first activity (which of course called the second one) I have onActivityResult, how am I getting a List out of the Intent again?

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == REAUTH_ACTIVITY_CODE) {
      uiHelper.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    } else if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {

      // Intent data to List<GraphUser> ?
    }
}
```

Or am I doing it totally wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I checked the documentation and, unfortunately GraphUser is not serializable.  What you can do  is to convert from List to List before calling setResult:

```
List<String> tmpList = new ArrayList<String>();
for (GraphUser tmp : friendList) {
  tmpList.add(tmp.getInnnerJSONObject().toString());
}
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.putExtra("list", tmpList);
setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
finish();
```

On onActivityResult, you can read the data back:

```
  else if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {

   List<String> tmpList = intent.getExtra("list");
   List<GraphUser> list = new ArrayList<GraphUser>();
   for (String tmpString : tmpList) {
       GraphUser user = (GraphUser) GraphObject.Factory.create(new JSONObject(tmpString), ,GraphUser.class);
       list.add(user);
   }
}
```

Check for `typo/null values/correct cast`

Comment: thank you, this worked almost flawlessly. A few corrections maybe for future references: intent.putStringArrayListExtra instead of intent.putExtra, List<GraphUser> list = new ArrayList<GraphUser>(); instead of List<GraphUser> list = new List<GraphUser>(); and user = (GraphUser) GraphObject.Factory.create(new JSONObject(tmpString),GraphUser.class); instead of user = (GraphUser) GraphObject.Factory.create(new JSONObject(tmpString));

but at this points that are only some minor things to fix, thank you again for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You can't just cast your list in an `Intent` object. Instead you have to put it in :

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.putExtra("foobar", friendListToPlay);
setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
finish();
```

back in your first Activity :

```
List<GraphUser> friendListToPlay = (Serializable) intent.getSerializableExtra("foobar");
```

Obviously the `GraphUser` class must implement the `Serializable` interface. If this is not the case, simply store a `String` representation of it, for example using JSON.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the Application object to transfer your data, if you want to keep the same reference and if the serialization is an issue for you.